# How to introduce Let keyword inside Linq statement with Group by

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have the following Linq statement with 'Group by' clause and would like to know how to introduce a let or any other statement to avoid repeating the sub query, `lifecycleEvents.Where(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key).First()` in the following example

```
var completionTimeModels =
    from timeline in processTimelines 
    group timeline by timeline.LifecycleEventId into grouping
    select new CompletionTimeViewModel()
    {
        // How to avoid repeating the same query to find the life cycle event?
        Name = lifecycleEvents.Where(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key).First().LifecycleEventName,
        DisplayName = lifecycleEvents.Where(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key).First().LifecycleEventDisplayName
    };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var completionTimeModels =
from timeline in processTimelines

group timeline by timeline.LifecycleEventId into grouping
let foo = lifecycleEvents.First(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key)
select new CompletionTimeViewModel()
{
    Name = foo.LifecycleEventName,
    DisplayName = foo.LifecycleEventDisplayName
};
```

Comment: All these answers are identical. It's really quite straightforward.

Comment: Use `First(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key)`

Comment: since the lifecycleeventid's are different we can have a number of grouping keys, so which key will take part in the query as grouping.Key?

Comment: @amesh, Because of the grouping every item in the group will have the same key. We are then picking out one item from lifecycleEvents for each group based on the group's key. The first call runs once per group.

Comment: Do you mean .First call? In a linq query how we can infer the calls which run once per item?

Comment: More clearly the default behaviour of .First will give only one item.Here the .First lambda is behaving is if its a .ForEeach. How it works?

Comment: The call to Group returns an IEnumerable of groups that is iterated over in the call to select, which also calls .First once per group. The .First call gets made once per group, it does not itself iterate over all groups.

Answer (score 2):

```
var completionTimeModels =
    from timeline in processTimelines
    group timeline by timeline.LifecycleEventId into grouping
    let lifecyleEvent = lifecycleEvents.Where(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key).First()
    select new CompletionTimeViewModel()
    {
        Name = lifecyleEvent.LifecycleEventName,
        DisplayName = lifecyleEvent.LifecycleEventDisplayName
    };
```

Comment: Use `First(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key)`

Comment: @abatishchev: Absolutely.  I'm surprised I didn't catch that myself.  Passing predicates to non-Where extension methods is one of my favorite underrated/underused linq techniques.

Answer (score 1):

```
var completionTimeModels =
    from timeline in processTimelines 
    group timeline by timeline.LifecycleEventId into grouping
    let current = lifecycleEvents.Where(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key).First()
    select new CompletionTimeViewModel()
    {
            // How to avoid repeating the same query to find the life cycle event?
        Name = current.LifecycleEventName,
        DisplayName = current.LifecycleEventDisplayName
    };
```

Comment: Use `First(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var completionTimeModels =
    from timeline in processTimelines 
    group timeline by timeline.LifecycleEventId into grouping
    let lifecyleEvent = lifecycleEvents.First(i => i.LifecycleEventId == grouping.Key)
    select new CompletionTimeViewModel()
    {
        // How to avoid repeating the same query to find the life cycle event?
        Name = lifecyleEvent.LifecycleEventName
        DisplayName = lifecyleEvent.LifecycleEventDisplayName
    };
```