# Linq "join" with a IList<T> getting "Error Unable to create a constant value.."

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have a Save Method that saves with a Linq query a *manually re-orderd list* (in a web form) that is *passed as the parameter to my method*, and I try to update the **Order Property** of the `IEnumerable<VM_CategoryLabel>` I retrieve from the database (EF) with the corresponding value in the list (maybe would that be clearer with my code below):

```
public static void SaveFromList(IList<VM_CategoryLabelExtra> listTemplate)
    {
        int idCat = listTemplate.Select(x => x.IdCat).FirstOrDefault();
        var test = (int)listTemplate.Where(z => z.Id == 8).Select(z => z.Order).FirstOrDefault();

        using (var context = new my_Entities())
        {
            var requete = from x in context.arc_CatLabel
                          where x.ID_Categorie == idCat
                          orderby x.Sequence_Cat
                          select new VM_CategoryLabel
                          {
                              Id = x.ID_LabelPerso,
                              //Order = x.Sequence_Cat,
                              Order = (int)listTemplate.Where(z => z.Id == x.ID_LabelPerso).Select(z => z.Order).First(),
                              Label = x.arc_Label.Label,
                              Unit = x.arc_Label.Unit
                          };
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I used the *"test" var* to see if my "sub-query" gets the correct value, and it does, but when I use my Linq expression inside the Select (the commented Order line), I get the following error:

**Unable to create a constant value of type 'Namespace.Models.VM_CategoryLabelExtra. "Only primitive types and enumeration types are supported in this context.**

Here are my classes:

```
       public class VM_CategoryLabel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class VM_CategoryLabelExtra
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdCat { get; set; }      
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

So I suppose that I should not query the list inside my query ? So how do I "match" the 2 lists of values ?

I also tried the following (after having replace in the Linq query: Order = x.Sequence_Cat)that is not working neither because the iteration variable is
read-only:

```
foreach (var item in requete)
                {
                    item.Order = listTemplate.Where(x => x.Id == item.Id).Select(x => x.Order).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                try
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I cant understant this "Order = (int)listTemplate.Where" and Order = x.Sequence_Cat? You cant use twice

Comment: when I uncomment the 2nd "Order" I comment the first one (that get the values actually in the database). So I only use 1 Order in my query :)

Comment: @Bro I like your avatar/picture. Is that really you?

Comment: Did you try its such http://screencast.com/t/pXY8KMQg82r

Comment: @Elvin I tried your suggestion, and I get the same error message

Comment: @KingKing: lol it's never too late to start learning right ? but this old man is someone I photographed last year :)

Comment: @Bro, I create screenshot for info,, you must change it as you need.

Comment: @Elvin: I tried with your code with: Order = z.Order and I had the same error message

Comment: Maybe should I do something like a SQL join ?

Comment: I tried the "linq join" ( join L in listTemplate on x.ID_LabelPerso equals L.Id ) but as soon as I introduce listTemplate I have the error... any idea ?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx).

It is the `let` clause.

```
public static void SaveFromList(IList<VM_CategoryLabelExtra> listTemplate)
    {
        int idCat = listTemplate.Select(x => x.IdCat).FirstOrDefault();
        var test = (int)listTemplate.Where(z => z.Id == 8).Select(z => z.Order).FirstOrDefault();

    using (var context = new my_Entities())
    {
        var requete = from x in context.arc_CatLabel
                      where x.ID_Categorie == idCat
                      orderby x.Sequence_Cat
                      let list = listTemplate                                     
                      select new VM_CategoryLabel
                      {
                          Id = x.ID_LabelPerso,                              
                          Order = list.Where(z => z.Id == x.ID_LabelPerso).Select(z => z.Order).First(),                             
                          Label = x.arc_Label.Label,
                          Unit = x.arc_Label.Unit
                      };
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**edit: instead of**`from` **you can just do** `let list = listTemplate`

**Should work now :)**

Comment: Pim, I tried that and VS is saying that the list (on the line list.Where...) does not exist in the context

Comment: try again i forgot to select at the end of the `let`

Comment: same same. I updated the error message (complete translation) and it's like it's not permitted to execute the included query (list.Where...)

Comment: as soon as I include "let list = from q in listTemplate select q" in the query (even if I don't use the "list" in the "Order = list...") I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

example for let:

```
// The let keyword in query expressions comes in useful with subqueries: it lets
// you re-use the subquery in the projection:

from c in Customers
let highValuePurchases = c.Purchases.Where (p => p.Price > 1000)
where highValuePurchases.Any()
select new
{
    c.Name,
    highValuePurchases
}
```

If you do not know how Let working than please download LinqPad and see an example

Comment: it seems that the let clause is made for " to store the result of a sub-expression in order to use it in subsequent clauses", but this is not the case here ?

Comment: You can use the result inside your subquery look to this example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596899/how-to-introduce-let-keyword-inside-linq-statement-with-group-by)

Comment: let list = list.Where(z => z.Id == x.ID_LabelPerso).Select(z => z.Order).First(),        ---> in your query below.