# Linq update with an Ilist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, crud

I would like to update my database datas and I have the following 2 "lists" of element :

1. Linq Query returning me an `IQueryable<VM_CategoryLabel>` from the database (that has to be updated)
2. `IList<VM_CategoryLabelExtra>` (list coming from a web interface)

Here are my 2 classes:

```
    public class VM_CategoryLabel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class VM_CategoryLabelExtra
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdCat { get; set; }      
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

It seems so basic, but I get an error and [was unsuccessful trying with Linq to join or with the let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183892/linq-join-with-a-ilistt-getting-error-unable-to-create-a-constant-value). Maybe the way I am doing it is totally wrong ?

Comment: What is your issue? Updating the DB? Or returning results as per your last question?

Comment: So, are you asking the same question again?

Comment: I cannot update inside a Linq query (if you follow the link I put, this is the way I was trying to do my update) getting an error "Unable to create a constant value of type..." So I was thinking that I had to change the way I was thinking to update my db, maybe with a foreach loop or I don't know..

Comment: Are you trying to update your `IQueryable` list with the data in the `IList` passed from the web interface?

Comment: @ataravati: no I think the way I was doing was wrong, so I ask another way to do it

Comment: @Dave Zych: yes that's my goal

Comment: I am beginner an self learning, so when sticking 2 days on such a problem I become crazy... I don't know in which way to look

Comment: I saw the link that you provided. I think thats not the correct way to update your DB. First of all you are doing a SELECT but not doing anything to change the selected objects. So hitting save changes will not help. You need to iterate through the list make necessary changes to the objects in the same context and then SaveChanges()

Comment: @Nilesh: thanks, so I cannot do my (Order = (int)listTemplate.Where...) inside my Linq query ? because that Linq query is a Select ?

Comment: Your "new" item isn't attached to the context. Either use var catLabel = context.Create<VM_CategoryLabel>(); and set the properties of catLabel before calling savechanges or attach the new VM_CategoryLabel you are selecting to the context.

Comment: To update the entities you need to Iterate over the List that you got from the select 
like this `requete.ToLisT().Foreach(x=> {
                    x.Order = (int)listTemplate.Where(z => z.Id == x.ID_LabelPerso).Select(z => z.Order).First()
                        });`
Is the VM_CategoryLabel a EF POCO Entity? if not you need to add one more step which creates List of a EF POCO entities and then attach them to the Context.

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction Lee O and Nilesh :)
In fact I was dealing with View Model classes that have nothing to do with the context and the context entities...